# Printing index of keywords in listings for first mention only

Tags: listings, imakeidx

I am writing a technical report, which integrates chunks of code using `listings`.

I would like to add an index of the `keywords` used in the listings (using `index=[1][keywords]`), but reporting in the index only the *first* page in which the keyword is  mentioned--because that's where I introduced it in the text.

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\lstdefinelanguage{minion}{ % define the "minion language", known for its semantic complexity
morekeywords={bello,banana} % keywords for the "minion language"
}

\lstset{language=minion, % settings for the language
    frame=single, % box arround the code
    keywordstyle=\color{YellowOrange},
    index=[1][keywords]% index the keywords
}

\begin{document}
We introduce the commands \lstinline!bello! and \lstinline!banana!
\begin{lstlisting}
say(bello)
eat(banana)
\end{lstlisting}
\newpage
\begin{lstlisting}
bello
\end{lstlisting}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Using `makeidx` and `\printindex` creates an index for *every page* in which a given keyword is mentioned in the listings (e.g., `bello` is reported in pages 1 and 2 in the index).

I would like to show an index containing only the *first* page in which any given keyword is mentioned (i.e., `bello` and `banana` in page 1 only in the example).

I'm pretty sure there must be an easy solution for this, but could not find it.

Comment: Could you please add a minimal example of a complete document showing the problem? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`; add just a couple of listings on separate pages (use `\clearpage` to produce two pages) with a couple of keywords you need to be indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a solution with `indexstyle`, but the manual is rather cryptic on the subject.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\lstdefinelanguage{minion}{   % define the "minion language", known for its semantic complexity
  morekeywords={bello,banana} % keywords for the "minion language"
}

\lstset{language=minion, % settings for the language
  frame=single, % box around the code
  keywordstyle=\color{YellowOrange},
  index=[1][keywords]% index the keywords
}

\renewcommand{\lstindexmacro}[1]{%
  \ifcsname alreadyindexed#1\endcsname
    % do nothing, the keyword has already been indexed
  \else
    % globally define the stopper macro
    \global\expandafter\let\csname alreadyindexed#1\endcsname\empty
    % index the keyword
    \index{#1@\texttt{#1}}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
We introduce the commands \lstinline!bello! and \lstinline!banana!
\newpage
\begin{lstlisting}
say(bello)
eat(banana)
\end{lstlisting}
\newpage
\begin{lstlisting}
bello
\end{lstlisting}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Here's the produced `.idx` file

```
\indexentry{bello@\texttt  {bello}}{1}
\indexentry{banana@\texttt  {banana}}{1}
```

Comment: Nice macro! Thank you for for writing it. I didn't find anything on the makeidx manual either.